# HtmlButton not running client side validation in IE11

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer-11, asp.net-4.5

I having an odd issue with a web form using the [HTMLButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8fd2268%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in asp.net.  For formatting reasons i need to use a `<button>` construct which is fine, it works in every other browser tested but IE11.

```
<button id="cmdLogin" runat="server" OnServerClick="cmdLogin_OnServerClick" class="btn btn-more" ValidationGroup="Login" CausesValidation="True">
    Login
</button>
```

When i place a standard asp.net button control, it works, the client side validation is run.  The difference i can see between the buttons is the onclick function that ASP.Net injects:

```
if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate('ModalLogin'); __doPostBack('ctl00$scriptsFooterPlaceholder$TDF971800010$cmdLogin','')
```

I know that IE11 had some issues with `__doPostBack` .Net 4 for but i am on .Net 4.51, so i don't think it is that.  There are no JavaScript errors that i can see that would stop it (and with the standard button test i guess the client side script is working) and in every other browser i have tested (Chrome, FF, Safari, IE8, IE9, IE10) it is working, just IE11.

Anyone seen this sort of issue?

Answer (score 0):

I thought i would try and hijack the click event in IE11 and see if i could manually force the validation. It turned out to be easier as going through the process the code below, "fixes" the IE11 issue:

```
   <script>
   var isIE11 = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);
   if (isIE11) {
       $('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
       });
   }
```

The `preventDefault` does it, but what is odd is it actually allows the client side validation to work as expected, i.e. it gets caught without forcing a postback (before this the client side stuff was ignored and all forms were validated on postback), so this "fix" is not stopping the client side validation from working.

**Note:** I do not like or advocate sniffing the browser and version, but in this case as it is only IE11 that has this behavior and i am going to do more research into it after i get this project out the door.  It seems like a bug in IE11 with .Net and using the HtmlButton construct which may need a patch from Microsoft.